# Error: Unrecognized instruction format: <PrefetchDataset shapes: {image: (None, None, 3), label: ()}, types: {image: tf.uint8, label: tf.int64}>

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I am trying the following code:

```
test_split, valid_split, train_split = tfds.load('tf_flowers', split ['train[:10%]','train[:15%]','train[:75%]']) 

test_set = tfds.load("tf_flowers",split=test_split, as_supervised=True)
```

But I get the following error
Unrecognized instruction format: <PrefetchDataset shapes: {image: (None, None, 3), label: ()}, types: {image: tf.uint8, label: tf.int64}>

Thank you

Comment: what makes you think that `test_split` is a valid argument to pass to `tfds.load()`?

Comment: I am trying to follow a chapter from Hands on Machine Learning, but the code they use seems to be depreciated so I am not sure if this line is proper

Comment: I don't think tfds was ever like that

Answer (score 1):

I have mentioned sample code to import tensorflow dataset:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
(train_ds, val_ds, test_ds), metadata = tfds.load('tf_flowers',
                                                  split=['train[:80%]', 'train[80%:90%]', 'train[90%:]'],
                                                  with_info=True,
                                                  as_supervised=True)
```

You can follow this code to import your dataset and let us know if still issue persists.

For more details on tensorflow datasets , please check this reference [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images#using_tensorflow_datasets).